# Remove line from file using Groovy scripting

Tags: groovy

Being new to groovy I have been struggling with a simple task of removing a line and adding a new one to a file (properties.file). I cannot find a proper and easy solution for this case.

The actual objective is to change the ApplicationVersion value with each new application release. The version will be set from a different variable ($version) that will change with each release. After different approaches I got to the conclusion that removing the line entirely and adding a new one would be the simplest solution.

1. Considering the following application.properties file how can I remove line 3 and add a new one instead
2. Or how could I use a solution with a substring to change the hardcoded version of 3.5.7 with a new $version (that will be set from different files).

```
# Application configuration

ApplicationVersion                      = 3.5.7
XmlMetadataFile                         = metadata.xml

DataPath                                = /home/dev/data
# linux: /home/app/data
# win: c:/data/

ApplicationLocaleLanguage               = GB
ApplicationLocaleCountry                = GB
```

An option would have been:

```
def applicationProperties = new File("/Users/user/app/resources/application.properties")
def fileText = applicationProperties('UTF-8')

fileText = (fileText =~ /3.5.7/).replaceAll("$version")
applicationProperties.write(fileText)
```

However this works only once. For the following version update, the solution (fileText =~ /3.5.7/) will not work as 3.5.7 will not be found since the previous update.

Comment: Do you need to keep the formatting and comments?

Comment: You could turn the file into a template, where you define a placeholder for the actual version, e. g. `ApplicationVersion = _VERSION_`. Then the task would be as simple as `def file = new File(path); file.text = file.text.replaceAll('_VERSION_', newVersion)`

Comment: Please add your attempts and how they failed (logs, stacktraces, ...) or how they don't produce what you expect.

Comment: @zett42 - That solution is inefficient as it only works once. The ApplicationVersion is automatically set from some other file and it will always vary. Once the ApplicationVersion = VERSION will be set automatically, the replaceAll will not find the first argument for the next update iteration as it has already been previously changed.

Comment: it sounds like a step of your build process

Comment: @injecteer - it is indeed a step from the build process ;)

Comment: That was only simplified. You could keep the template and store the result of the replace in another file.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution to the problem. This solution creates a new empty line and appends "ApplicationVersion\t\t\t\t= " + $version + "\n" to it if line of interest found in the properties document.

Still uncertain of how this works.

a. Does it overwrite the line of interest ? 
b. Does it create a new document that gets overwritten ?

```
def applicationProperties = new File("/Users/user/app/resources/application.properties")
def fileText = applicationProperties.getText('UTF-8')

def newLine = '';
def version = 9.1.1;
fileText.eachLine {
    if (it =~ /ApplicationVersion/) {
        newLine += "ApplicationVersion\t\t\t\t= " + version + "\n"
    } else {
        newLine += it + "\n"
    }
}

applicationProperties.write(newLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a step of you build process, you can use some Gradle magic with `filter`.

Something like

```
ext.version = '11.24.3'

task processIndex( type:Copy ) {
  from 'src/main/webapp/build'
  into "$buildDir/resources/main"
  filter{ 
    it.replaceAll( 'ApplicationVersion([\s]*=[\s]*)([\d\.]+)"/', 'ApplicationVersion$1' + ext.version )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple one-line solution with `AntBuilder`.

```
def version = '1.1.2'
new AntBuilder().replaceregexp(file: 'application.properties', match: /(ApplicationVersion[\s]*=[\s]*).*/, replace: /\1/ + version)
```